# Set max-height using javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have a div, and the maximum width for this div is user defined. I know I can get it done using element.style.height but this doesn't work in IE.

Any ideas on how to implement the max-height equivalent of Firefox by using javascript?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Usually style attribute names are translated into javascript property names by removing the hyphens and camelcase the name instead.

So `background-color` becomes `backgroundColor`, `text-align` becomes `textAlign` and `max-height` becomes `maxHeight`.

You can set an element `el`'s maximum height to `mHeight` by:

`el.style.maxHeight=mHeight;`

Remember to use a valid value for `mHeight`.

Comment: Just for clarity, a "valid value for `mHeight`" would be a string which includes units, exactly as in CSS. E.g., `mHeight = "100px"`, not `mHeight = 100`.

Comment: Just for more clarity, it may also be `"0"`, a percentage string (`"50%"`) or `"none"`, all of these are valid values for `max-height` (the corresponding CSS property), see http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#min-max-heights

Answer (score 6):

```
document.getElementById ( "yourelementid" ).style.maxHeight = "100px";
```

See **[maxHeight Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530809(VS.85).aspx)**

> maxHeight was introduced in Windows
>   Internet Explorer 7

Answer (score 2):

To make the animation time match what is expected, I would use `el.scrollHeight` to find the required height of the element.

Comment: Looks like this might be an answer to some other question...? :-) Or am I missing something? :-)

Comment: Yes, I meant to reply to the top answer. Sorry - I've not used StackOverflow much.