# Making the leaflet layer control panel responsive with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet

I have too many lines on my leaflet layer control, such that it spills beyond the page. How can I do the [below](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/leaflet-js/aoImrdIoF2Q) using javascript?

```
.leaflet-control-layers {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

#### What I've tried

1. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2244798/4047679)

   ```
   var controls = L.control.layers(null,overlayMaps,{collapsed: false});  
   controls.addTo(map);  
   controls.style.overflow="auto";
   ```

   I got that the controls didn't have a `style` attribute
2. The second answer to the same question

   ```
   document.getElementById("leaflet-control-layers").style.overflow="auto";
   ```

   Nothing happens
3. Not sure where I got this, but I guess jQuery wasn't being used in my map

   ```
   $(".leaflet-control-layers").style.overflow="auto";
   ```

   Since this printed `ReferenceError: $ is not defined` to the console.
4. From the accepted answer to [Modify CSS classes using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23348456/modify-css-classes-using-javascript)

   ```
       var layercontrols = document.querySelectorAll('.leaflet-control-layers');
       for(var i=0; i<layercontrols.length; i++){
           layercontrols[i].style.overflow="auto";
       }
   ```

   (nothing happens)

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to set the div's overflow to auto I don't see why you can't do it in CSS. However I think the reason .style.overflow didn't work is because you did document.getElementById() when 'leaflet-control-layers' is the class not the ID.

Comment: If I get the CSS source from a CDN, is it possible to edit it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.